# strange behaviour on another process via Process.Start(startInfo)

Tags: c#, .net

Our C# (V3.5) application needs to call another C++ executable which is from another company. we need to pass a raw data file name to it, it will process that raw data (about 7MB) file and generate 16 result files (about 124K for each).

The code to call that executable is this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = exePath;
startInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;
try
{
Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
correctionProcess.WaitForExit();
}
catch(nvalidOperationException ex)
{
....
}
catch(...)
...
```

It works fine. Now we have new raw data. After replace the old raw data with the new raw data file. That executable process never return to us. It will hang forever. If we kill our C# application, those result files will be generated in the target directoy. It looks like the executable does create those result files but has issue to write to the disk and return to us until the process is terminated.

It is NOT like this with the old raw data file.

When we run the executable with the new raw data directly (no from our C# app call), it works fine. This means this executable has no problem with the new raw data.

My question 1: what's the possible causes for this behaviour?

Now I change our code with `startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` and add `startInfo.WorkingDirectory= ...,` and disabled

```
//startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
//startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Then it works.

My question 2: why use Windows Shell solve this issue?

My question 3: why it works before without using Shell?

My question 4: when we should use Shell and When shouldn't?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possibilities:

- You are redirecting output and error but not reading it.  The process will stall when its stdout or stderr buffer fills up to capacity.
- The program might be displaying an error message and waiting for a keypress.  You are not redirecting input nor check stderr, that keypress will never come.
- Some programs, xcopy.exe is a very good example, require stdin to be redirected when you redirect stdout.  Although the failure mode for xcopy.exe is an immediate exit without any diagnostic.

Seeing it fixed when you kill your C# program makes the first bullet the likeliest reason.

Comment: I have tested several different combinations. I found only two cases work for me: 1. use window shell; 2. not use window shell and not redirect error and output. don't know why. I have print out (to log file) to get the string from the redirected Error and Output. But nothing was logged. That means there was no error or output message at all!

Comment: If you use the shell then you'll never redirect, slam dunk for a fix, minus the console window that shows up.  If you don't see it then it might be hiding behind your own window, consider the problem solved.  Without the shell and redirect enabled, reading stdout and stderr is a hard requirement.  You haven't shown us what that code looks like.

Comment: I added code in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502732/strange-behaviour-on-another-process-via-process-startstartinfo-continue

Comment: Erm, which one do you want me to answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know this, it is a very common problem. I has to do with the output, which must be handled asynchronously. You just can't WaitForExit when output exceeds certain amount of data.

You need to add

```
myStdErr= correctionProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Only once usually works, if you want to overkill this works ("P" being my Process)

```
while (!P.HasExited)
  stdErr+= P.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the stdout/stderr, just turn the Redirect* properties to false.

Comment: yes, it works if I turn off those Redirect properties, but why it doesn't work if I have them on and read them to the end already?