# strange behaviour on another process via Process.Start(startInfo) -- continue

Tags: c#, .net, process

The original location ([strange behaviour on another process via Process.Start(startInfo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451434/strange-behaviour-on-another-process-via-process-startstartinfo)) doesn't allow me post test code properly. I have to start a new question here.

Our C#(V3.5) needs to call a C++ executable to process a raw data file and generate result files for us.

It worked before with the following code (without ReadToEnd() or ReadLine() call):

```
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Now the input raw data file changed (bigger than before). Our call to that executable will hang forever. Based on advice, I added ReadToEnd() or ReadLine() but it will hang on those calls.  So I have to either use `startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` or set

```
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
// and with
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

Don't know why?

Following are cases I tested:

1. working case:

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   startInfo.FileName = path;
   startInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;
   //startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Util.GetParentDirectory(path, 1);
   try
   {
       Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
       correctionProcess.WaitForExit();
   }
   ```
2. working case:

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;//can be commented out
   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;//can be commented out
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   startInfo.FileName = path;
   startInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;
   startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Util.GetParentDirectory(path, 1);
   try
   {
       Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
       correctionProcess.WaitForExit();
   }
   ```
3. NOT working case (using `ReadLine()`):

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   startInfo.FileName = path;
   startInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;
   //startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Util.GetParentDirectory(path, 1);
   try
   {
       Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
       while (!correctionProcess.HasExited)
       {
           Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read errorMsg @@@@", "DPTM::correctData()", "");
           string errorMsg = correctionProcess.StandardError.ReadLine(); // <-- Hangs here
           Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read errorMsg", "DPTM::correctData()", "errorMsg=" + errorMsg);
           string outputMsg = correctionProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
           Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read outputMsg", "DPTM::correctData()", "outputMsg=" + outputMsg);
           Thread.Sleep(100);
       }
   }
   ```
4. NOT working case (using `ReadToEnd()`):

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   startInfo.FileName = path;
   startInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;
   //startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Util.GetParentDirectory(path, 1);
   try
   {
       Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
       while (!correctionProcess.HasExited)
       {
           Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read errorMsg @@@@", "DPTM::correctData()", "");
           string errorMsg = correctionProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // <-- Hangs here!
           Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read errorMsg", "DPTM::correctData()", "errorMsg=" + errorMsg);
           string outputMsg = correctionProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
           Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read outputMsg", "DPTM::correctData()", "outputMsg=" + outputMsg);
           Thread.Sleep(100);
       }
   }
   ```
5. NOT working case:

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   startInfo.FileName = path;
   startInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;
   //startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Util.GetParentDirectory(path, 1);
   try
   {
       Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
       Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read errorMsg @@@@", "DPTM::correctData()", "");
       string errorMsg = correctionProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // <-- Hangs here!
       Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read errorMsg", "DPTM::correctData()", "errorMsg=" + errorMsg);
       string outputMsg = correctionProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
       Log.logItem(LogType.Performance, "read outputMsg", "DPTM::correctData()", "outputMsg=" + outputMsg);
       correctionProcess.WaitForExit();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are deadlocked on the error/output buffer. Your second process is waiting for the buffer to free up while you are waiting for that process to finish. You need to asynchronously read output/error streams to prevent that.

Looking at your MSDN sample: wow that sample is really confusing... It would've been easier to follow if they just limited it to std out or std error.

You need to first set data handler

```
correctionProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputDataHandler);
```

and then call

```
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Just like comment [confusingly] advises do no try to read output there. Use handler instead.

```
    private void OutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs data)
    {
        if (data.Data != null)
        {
            // append data.Data to your internal buffer (StringBuilder?)
        }
    }
```

Comment: The following is the sample code from Miscrosoft. My case 5 is the same as it. it is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: so... I'm not sure what are you saying.